# Why is Quit disabled in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, applications

Recently, when I try to quit Mail, the Quit menu option is actually disabled and the keyboard shortcut doesn't work (it "beeps" just like when you try to do anything that isn't permitted). Screenshot for proof:

[image]

Any idea what's causing this and how I can prevent it from happening? The only "solution" I've found is to force quit Mail...

I'm running Mail 6.2 on 10.8.2.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the whole window. We can’t figure out what is going on just from the screenshot you gave. And we don’t need proofs, we trust you :)

Comment: Maybe a dialog box is still open, could also be on another space (if you use Spaces)

Comment: That keeps happening to me as well. It could have something to do with sandboxing, because it started in 10.7 and also affects some other sandboxed applications.

Comment: I've seen this behavior too, I guess `Mail.app` is syncing, cleaning something up, etc, and hangs. My experience is that it seldom goes back to a state in which you can quit it with Command-Q, so I usually revert to pressing Command-Shift-Option-Esc for a couple of seconds...

Comment: I've suspected it's a webkit issue.  I had it occur in Safari several times but never enough time to really investigate.  With it affecting Mail as well webkit is the main tie that first comes to mind.

Answer (score -1):

This problem has [previously been reported](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2537) and apparently hasn't been resolved. Apple's solution is to force quit Mail. If you are not especially loving Mail, and don't mind upgrading, [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) is an excellent replacement option. I use it on a daily basis, and it never has issues. Hope this helps!

Comment: I would find it hard to believe that any app never has issues. As you will see here in the recently active section of  https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/